# Azure Databricks only gets Event Hub Data sent while its runnng

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to read Azure Event Hub data using databricks.

I have a producer running in nodejs, as well as a consumer for testing (on a different consumer group) and all seems to be running fine.

I am using the following pyspark code in databricks to get the data:

```
# Initialize event hub config dictionary with connectionString
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://XXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test;SharedAccessKey=XXX;EntityPath=XXX"
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
 
# Add consumer group to the ehConf dictionary
ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = "databricks"
 
# Read events from the Event Hub
messages = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
 
# Visualize the Dataframe in realtime
display(messages)
```

The issue is that it only reads data from the stream if it is sent while the notebook is running. If i produce data and then run the notebook, it does not appear.

What am I missing? I want to use this to collect data from the stream every hour or so and save it.

Config:
Databricks Runtime: 7.3LTS (Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)
Azure eventhub library: `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.21`

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems:

1. `display` by default is using a temporary checkpoint, so when you run it next time, it don't know where to continue, so it starts again & again.  If you continue to use `display`, add the `checkpointLocation="some_path" to the display call (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#structured-streaming-dataframes))
2. by default, EventHubs connector reads only new data (that's why it consumes data only when running) - if you want to consume data from beginning (only on the initial call) - you need to add option `eventhubs.startingPositions` that encodes starting positions (see [doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#event-hubs-configuration)) - to start reading from beginning of the topic, assign following to this option:

```py
import json

startingEventPosition = {
  "offset": -1,  
  "seqNo": -1,            #not in use
  "enqueuedTime": None,   #not in use
  "isInclusive": True
}

ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(startingEventPosition)
```

Comment: Really, it's better to use Kafka connector to consume data from the EventHubs - it's more performant & stable. Here is an example of configuration: https://alexott.blogspot.com/2022/06/delta-live-tables-recipes-consuming.html