# Unable to Stream Data from Azure Event Hubs to Databricks: Query Returns No Results

Tags: azure, streaming, databricks, azure-eventhub

I am attempting to perform data streaming using Azure Event Hubs and Databricks. I have set up the Event Hub account and obtained the connection string for the Event Hub. In the Azure portal, I can see the incoming data requests and throughput in the console. However, when I try to stream this data into Databricks, the output indicates that the query returned no results.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the data is not being streamed or read successfully. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is the code i am using to stream the data:

```py
eventHubConf = {}
connectionString = """Endpoint=sb://*********.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=**********;SharedAccessKey=***********;EntityPath=**********"""

eventHubConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs") \
    .options(**eventHubConf) \
    .option("eventhubs.consumerGroup", "$Default") \
    .load()

display(df)
```

Even when I try to read the data without streaming, the query does not return any results. Here is the code I used to read the data:

```py
df = spark.read.format("eventhubs").option("eventhubs.connectionString", connectionString).load()

display(df)
```

The connection string used is the same as mentioned above.
Here is the screenshot of the Azure console of Eventhubs.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70580815/azure-databricks-only-gets-event-hub-data-sent-while-its-runnng/70581132#70581132

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexOtt given you need to add **eventhubs.startingPosition** option to your code for getting data from starting.

Code:

```
import json
eventHubConf = {}
pos = {
    "offset": -1,
    "seqNo": -1,
    "enqueuedTime": None,
    "isInclusive": True
    }
    
connstring = < Your connection string>"
eventHubConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connstring)

df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs")\
    .options(**eventHubConf)\
    .option("eventhubs.consumerGroup", "$Default")\
    .option("eventhubs.startingPosition",json.dumps(pos))\
    .load()
    
df2 = df.select(df.body.cast(StringType()).alias("word"))
display(df2)
```

Output:

[image]

Know i am sending data from event hub.

[image]

Below is the result.

[image]